# COUNTIF across multiple sheets does not work with SUMPRODUCT

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, countif

I have the two sheets below.

[image]

[image]

(The example table above is highly simplified for this question)

I'm trying to write a formula that adds the total occurrences of A under the year 2017 (Answer is 3).

This formula works if I add two COUNTIFs together for each sheet:

`=COUNTIF(INDEX(Sheet2!A2:C4, 0, MATCH(2017, Sheet2!A2:C2, 0)), "A") + COUNTIF(INDEX(Sheet3!A2:C4, 0, MATCH(2017, Sheet3!A2:C2, 0)), "A")`

I tried to combine them into a single formula below. However I'm getting a #Value error. "Sheets" is a named range consisting of {Sheet2, Sheet3}.

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!"&"A2:C4"), 0, MATCH(2017, INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!"&"A2:C2"), 0)), "A"))`

Why is the above formula giving me an error when I try to use the named range?

Comment: Match and Index do not work with 3D worksheet arrays.

Comment: I doubt that there is any method with formula to do this outside doing them individually.  VBA may be your only method to simplify

Answer (score 0):

*I've successfully reproduced the first formula between sheets and is working, but the `SUMPRODUCT` needs little correction and it should be written like this, and you get correct result **3** :*

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!A3:C4"),"A")-COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!A2:C2"),"2017"))
```

**N.B.**

- Where `Sheets` is the named range consists sheet's name are involved with the used formula.
- In the above formula, it first find the number of cells that have a value `A` are `5` & then subtracts the count of cells with a value `2017`, are `2`, then the formula returns `3`,,, `(5 As - 2 2017s) = 3` .
- *If you use `+` sign usually used with multiple `COUNTIF`, then in your case you get 7, and if COUNTIF is separated by `,` the formula returns `5`*

**:Edited:**

*Since sometimes above shown formula doesn't works properly therefore I would like to suggest this array (CSE) formula:*

```
{=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$A$170:$C$170),IF(Sheet1!$A$170:$C$170=2017,IF(Sheet1!$A$171:$C$172="A",1))))+SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet2!$A$170:$C$170),IF(Sheet2!$A$170:$C$170=2017,IF(Sheet2!$A$171:$C$172="A",1))))}
```

[image]

- Finish it with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

Comment: Sorry this does not work on different sets of data. For example, if Sheet 3 column 2016 had A,A instead of C,C, then your formula would return 5, which is incorrect.

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt,, now check edited part of my post & the formula along with screen shot  solves the issue, and returns `3` regardless of `As` in other columns.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I'm looking for. I don't want to reference every sheet individually. It's not scalable for hundreds of sheets.

Comment: I will have to resort to a VBA script instead it seems. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt,, glad to learn that you got VBA method,, **but nowhere you have mentioned that working with 100 sheets**,,  plzz post it as an answer,, helpful to community,, and keep asking !!